# Insert a textfield or checkbox on mouse click at current mouse position or drag and drop it

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am trying to insert a checkbox or textfield dynamicly on a mouse click at the mouseposition anywhere on the page or even better a drag and drop of textfields and checkboxes to any position of the page.

goal is it to add editable textfields and checkboxes to a page like [this](http://vz275.worldserver.net/converter/files/38053/38053.html)

would be great if someone could help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for replying late, was testing actually ;) Try SOMETHING(modify the logic according to your needs) like this:

```
$('body').click(function(e){ $('body').append($('<input />').css({position:'absolute',left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY}).focus());})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Draggle-Jquery plugin. [Documentation and Demo](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

You just have to add jquery files and this simple code:

```
 $(function() {
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
 });
```

html(you can use other html elements):

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

[Some more demos](http://coursesweb.net/jquery/drag-drop)

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought:

**Create a reusable input field (template)**

```
var $textinput = '<input type="text" value="" style="position:absolute" />';
```

**Add click handler to the page**

```
// Using jquery
$('body').on('click', function(event) {
    var posX = event.offsetX;
    var posY = event.offsetY;
    var $input = $textinput
    this.append($input);
    $input.css('{x: posX, y: posY}');
});
```

**Then just send all the values back to server on save**

Comment: You'll have to play a little bit converting the $textinput string into a cached DOM element so that you can set the x and y position.