# Input (Text field) --- Focus() not working

Tags: jquery, focus, textfield, slickgrid

There are many questions about `focus()` however I could not find any working solution for my problem.

I am using Slick Grid with some columns:

`{id: "Something", name: "Something", field: "Something", width: 200, editor: Slick.Editors.Text }`

```
var ResourcesGridOptions = {
        editable: true,
        enableCellNavigation: true,        
        enableColumnReorder: false,
        autoEdit: false
    };
```

I implemented a button to create new rows. Now I would like to automatically focus the input text. At this point I am able to set the mode "edit" on, but the `focus()` does not work.

Perhaps someone could help me out.

In Chrome Javascript console I am using:

```
$($('.slick-cell:eq(2)').dblclick().find('input')[0]).select().val("").focus()
```

And the console returns:

```
[<input type="text" class="editor-text" value="">]
```

**Update 1**

I've tried to add an "Id" to this input field and then focus it directly.... didn't work.

```
$($('.slick-cell:eq(2)').dblclick().find('input')[0]).attr('id', 'Something')
$('#Something').focus()
```

Returns: `[<input type="text" class="editor-text" value="" id="Something">]`

Comment: +1, Yeah even in my answer post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009877/insert-a-textfield-or-checkbox-on-mouse-click-at-current-mouse-position-or-drag/15010222#15010222) contains 1 line code to create input element dynamically but when I try to focus it, it just wont work (focus).

Comment: I think the first `$` is not needed. just write `$('.slick-cell:eq(2)').dblclick().find('input').eq(0).attr('id', 'Something')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling following function on Click event of add button,

```
function AddNewRow() {
var dataLength = dataView.getLength();
//dataView.addItem({ "Id": -1 });
//dataView.refresh();
grid.gotoCell(dataLength, 0, true);
}
```